# Unable to locate same locator when running remotely with Jenkins. How to solve this issue?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

Unable to locate the same locator when running remotely with Jenkins. How to solve this issue?
I have added waits. Resized screens size like below. But nothing working

```
 Dimension d = new Dimension(1382,744); 
 //Resize the current window to the given dimension
 driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
```

Comment: what error you have received ?

Comment: Error is: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element

Comment: If you could share the element xpath details and proper error messages then it would be easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks for your time to ask and interest on this question. I have solved thisn problem with avoiding parent/ child nodes related xpath and used matched text for those specific elements.